# Getting nulls instead of an object using marshaling. VSTO Excel C#

Tags: c#, vsto, marshalling, excel-addins

Why is `wb` a null object?

What am I doing wrong?

```
Excel.Application ap = (Excel.Application)Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
Excel.Workbook wb = ap.ActiveWorkbook;
Excel.Worksheet ws = ap.ActiveSheet;
```

Comment: What does this have to do with the VSTO technology? Or Excel Add-ins? A more appropriate tag might be office-interop...

Comment: Are there any workbooks open in the currently running instance of Excel? What does ap.Workbooks.Count return?

Comment: Interop.Excel. Yes, it's addin work in open excel. Workbook opened. Yesterday I just closed the studio. Today I open, I launch and voila. Working. I do not know, apparently bugs in the studio. It's sad. I lost the evening. Yesterday I recompiled and did not do anything. I knew that I should work. Previously, it worked. That's all it was decided. Thank's man.

Comment: I do not understand why I was neglected ... Cruel people from the IT world.

Answer (score 0):

The bug of VS. Today start and it work. Magic.

Answer (score 0):

The bug of VS. Today start and it work. Magic. Today it all worked again, but not for long. Marshaling began to catch a book in which the sheets are defaulted. Replaced all this miracle by Globals.Addins ...